# Oraclizer does not respond periodically

Tags: oracles, random

Contract that use oraclizer work just fine from moment of deploy. But three days ago oraclizer start to ignore requests  of my contract(not allways).

In [this trx](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xc1a900173b726c523676e9d13e4519b96098bf0c226769126f9521537d44ba2e) oracle dont return callback, but when i make request again affter 15 hour - it returning required callback.

Code from contract:

```
    function callOracleRandom() internal {
        oraclize_setProof(proofType_Ledger); // sets the Ledger authenticity proof
        uint N = 16; // number of random bytes we want the datasource to return
        uint delay = 0; // number of seconds to wait before the execution takes place
        // this function internally generates the correct oraclize_query and returns its queryId
        oraclize_newRandomDSQuery(delay, N, oraclizeGasLimit);
    }
```

Could i make a mistake?
Can it be posible in minenet?

Comment: Well it's a centralized service so it can be down or may refuse connections for whatever reason. You should contact their support to try to figure out why this happened.